# How to remove some data not needed on new row from mysql query with rollup

Tags: mysql, group-by

Hello I have a problem with the rollup mysql query. I want to get total of each column. I use mysql SUM() and ROLLUP to get the result. But on the new row that is added it copies the data of the last row. How can I remove those data. I provided an image on what I really needed to achieve.

Here is my query.

```
    SELECT  IFNULL(payments.id, "General Total"), payments.driver_id,
        payments.vehicle_specifications_id,payments.admins_id,
        payments.vehicle_id, payments.boundaries, payments.cashbond_payments,
        payments.loans, payments.penalties, SUM(payments.total_payments),
        a.first_name, a.mid_name, a.last_name, d2.date, d.first_name,
        d.mid_name, d.last_name, v.plate_number, v2.car_rate
    FROM  payments
    INNER JOIN  admins AS     a  ON payments.admins_id = a.id
    INNER JOIN  drivers AS    d  ON payments.driver_id = d.id
    INNER JOIN  dispatch AS   d2 ON payments.dispatch_id =d2.id
    INNER JOIN  vehicles AS   v  ON payments.vehicle_id = v.id
    INNER JOIN  vehicle_specifications AS v2
                ON payments.vehicle_specifications_id = v2.id
    GROUP BY  payments.id WITH ROLLUP
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Plan A (rather tedious):

```
IFNULL(payments.id, "General Total"),
IF(payments.id IS NULL, '', payments.driver_id),  -- conditionally blank each
...
```

Plan B:

```
( SELECT ... )  -- without ROLLUP
UNION ALL
( SELECT 'Grand Total', '', ... SUM(...), '', ... )  -- Just total
ORDER BY ...   -- to get "Grand Total" to be last
```

Comment: Thanks I already found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/48443988